# Python & tkinter: input names and then select one at random

Tags: python, random, tkinter

I have just started to learn how to program with Python from tutorials etc from the internet. I am currently trying to build a program where a user can input several names into an entry box and then one of the names then be selected at random.

I managed to do this using command line but am struggling to get it to work when building it as a GUI. For my command line code I used:

```
import random
import time

print ("Hello!")

userInput = input ('Please enter the names:')
time.sleep (5) 

userInput = str(userInput).split () 

name = random.choice (userInput)

print ("Its",name)
```

I was wondering how to create the same program but run it in a GUI. The code I have so far is:

```
import random
import time
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


def input():
    time.sleep (5)
    mytext=userInput.get()
    label2 = Label(root,text=mytext).pack()

userInput = StringVar()


root.geometry("500x500") 
root.title("Tkinter GUI")


Label1 = Label(root,text="Welcome to my program").pack() 

entry = Entry(root,textvariable=userInput).pack()



Button1 = Button(root,text="Go",command=input).pack() 


root.mainloop()
```

For my GUI based code I can enter some names etc but im not sure how I can have one selected at random. Can I still use the `.split()` & `random.choice` as per my text based code? Where in my GUI code would I need to enter this? I have tried several different places but have been unable to get it to work. I assume this is something which should be fairly easy to do? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `command` of your `Button` widget is attached to a callback function, in your case this function is called `input()`. Input isn't a great name for this function, because it already exists as a built-in function, and you don't want to re-define what it does. As another note, you should remove the time.sleep() from the callback, because time.sleep() conflicts with the GUI and disables updates to it while the process flow is asleep.

Within the callback function, you can process your input the same way you did before, then return it to the GUI however you'd like.

Example:

```
from tkinter import *
import random


def callback():
    nameList = userInput.get().split()
    name = random.choice(nameList)
    Label(root, text=name).pack()

root = Tk()

userInput = StringVar()

ent = Entry(root, textvariable=userInput)
ent.pack()
btn = Button(root, text="Go", command=callback)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

There's plenty of documentation and examples on Tkinter. Start here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm